# How to split text where new line starts with a capital letter

Tags: python, text

Trying to check readability for templated letters. Some aspects are sentences which end without punctuation. e.g. Enter your name/nEnter your address
I want to treat the /n(Capital Letter) as a new sentence but not new line lower case.

Imagine something like:

```
import re 
example = ' Please details\nPlease confirm :\npartnership'
re.split('[\n+isupper()]',example)
```

Desired outcome:

```
[' Please details', 'Please confirm : partnership']
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use positive lookahead `(?=...)` in your splitting pattern:

```
re.split('\n(?=[A-Z])',example)
[' Please details', 'Please confirm :\npartnership']
```

The lookahead is considered but *not consumed* for the matching. See the [docs on the `re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).